# PHP/ajax form not sending correctly

Tags: php, ajax, contact-form

I'm new to php and ajax.

I'm having an issue with a contact form I've created. It's not sending all of the information. I've isolated the issue and need an explanation as to why this is happening, I'll explain more below.

This is the HTML:

```
<section class="contact text-center " id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Actual Form -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                <article class="contact-form">
                    <form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
                        <!-- FIRST ROW -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First Name * ">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name *">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyname" placeholder="Company name *">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- SECOND ROW -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobtitle" placeholder="Job Title *">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Business Email *">
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number *">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right ">Submit</button>
                        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </form>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

This is the php for the form.

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// Last Name
if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $errorMSG = " Last Name is required ";
} else {
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
}

// Company Name
if (empty($_POST["companyname"])) {
    $errorMSG = " Company Name is required ";
} else {
    $companyname = $_POST["companyname"];
}

// Job Title
if (empty($_POST["jobtitle"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Job Title is required ";
} else {
    $jobtitle = $_POST["jobtitle"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// Phone Number
if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Phone Number is required ";
} else {
    $phonenumber = $_POST["phonenumber"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "farrun.wow@gmail.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";

$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Last Name: ";
$Body .= $lname;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Company Name: ";
$Body .= $companyname;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Job Title: ";
$Body .= $jobtitle;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Business Email Address: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Phone Number: ";
$Body .= $phonenumber;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

And this is the ajax:

```
    $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var companyname = $("#companyname").val();
    var jobtitle = $("#jobtitle").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var email = $("#phonenumber").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        //data: "name=" + name + "&lname=" + lname + "&companyname=" + companyname + "&jobtitle=" + jobtitle + "&email=" + email + "&phonenumber=" + phonenumber + "&message=" + message ,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

The issue is here with this line

```
data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
```

I can only have three entries in this, when I add any more to it the form breaks completely for some reason. The only three that send is "name", "email" and message"

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: What _exactly_ does "the form breaks completely" mean?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but only one of your `errorMsg`'s is a `.=` the others just overwrite one another.

Comment: You are specifying to js that this is a post and php is expecting a post, but you are formatting the data as a query string? is this intentional? does it even work?

Comment: @1252748 As far as I can remember, the query string is acceptable for a POST, yet I would recommend using `{ name, email, message, ...}` js object notation for simplification.

Comment: You should probably use .serialize to pass your form data through. As @1252748 said, you are structuring the data as a GET request instead of post. Try setting `var form_data = $('form').serialize();` and `data: form_data` to pass the form data through.

Comment: @GregMcMullen Could you edit the post with the HTML form please? (My bad, I looked wrong at the comment section)

Comment: @ReuelRamosRibeiro It's not my question. I don't know what his form looks like.

Comment: I would guess some of the `$("...").val()` are returning `undefined` because I am not sure if you've used `required` for the HTML inputs. Try to `console.log` your query string to see what you're actually trying to send.

Comment: @ReuelRamosRibeiro I've added the HTML to the post.

Comment: You are likely trying to send invalid data due to the fact that you're building a param string by hand without sanitizing it at all. jQuery even gives you a method to make this easy, $.param.

Comment: I should also mention that I am generally a designer and this was given to me by a client to "fix errors" and "improve upon". I'm not entirely sure wwhat some of these terms are I'm generally not all that involved with code.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few observations.

1. Your form is submitting as the default `GET` method. Setting `method="post"` will line things up with your PHP script.
2. Your form inputs are missing a crucial element to process the form data without setting them manually as you are doing. E.G. `name`. Each element should have a name, to be referenced in either a `post` or `get` request.
3. Your method in the AJAX call for assigning the variables could (and should) be much simpler. See my example below.
4. The onClick event `myFunction()` does not exist in the code sample you provided.

### Form HTML

Update the form method. Add `name="field"` to `input` and `textarea`.

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST">
  <input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" />
  <input name="lname" id="lname" type="text" />
  ... other fields
  <button id="contactSubmit" class="">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

### PHP

Can largely remain the same. Although, update the errorMsg to be as such.

// Init as empty

```
$errorMSG = '';

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    // Use .= to concat
    $errorMSG .= "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// Last Name
if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    // Use .= to concat
    $errorMSG .= " Last Name is required ";
} else {
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
}
...etc
```

### JavaScript

Structurally, you were pretty good. The AJAX is really all that changed.

```
function submitForm(){
    var formData = $('#contactForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "path/to/form-process.php",
      data: formData,
      success: function(text) {
          if (text == "success") {
              // debug
              console.log("success");
              // ... other functions
          } else {
              // debug
              console.log("error");
              // ... other functions
          }
      }
  });
}
```